# Send data inside HTML output or span tags to Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, forms, google-sheets, append

I'm trying to send data inside HTML output and span tags within a form to a Google Sheet. I can send the data that's inside the input tags, but not the data inside the other two types.

I've tried formData.append as below but it didn't work (maybe a syntax error). The id of the field is .

Here's the code:

```
const scriptURL = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/MYAPIKEY/exec"
        
        const form = document.forms['foo']

        formData.append('price', [data]'price');
      
        form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
          e.preventDefault()
          fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})

            .then(response => alert("Successful"))
            .catch(error => console.error('Unsuccessful', error.message))
        })
```

Comment: Found a solution using formData.append("name",var). Issue resolved.

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer below and then accept it. Just to keep things clean on the site, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. Many thanks.

```
var fetchBody = new FormData(form);

            fetchBody.append('outputRecommended', outputRecommended);
            fetchBody.append('price', price);

            fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: fetchBody})
```